# Send dataset to crystal report with no db connection in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, crystal-reports

i have a problem with make (dynamic) reports from sqlite database in crystal report .
i want to know that is there any way to send a dataset that isn't connected to database,to crystal report ?! i have seen a article in CodeProject for send dataset to crystal ! but i don't want and i can't use wizard way ! thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET DataSets are designed to work in disconnected mode, meaning that as opposed to DataReader the connection to the database is no longer required once data has been taken.

I can imagine that wizard you could use within Visual Studio and CR Designer requires an active connection to work and to allow you to store the dataset definition somewhere, it will probably be the result of a stored procedure call or an inline query but that should be needed only for the first time design.

Once populated the DataSet really contains the data and nothing is required anymore from the connection which could be closes immediately after the DataAdapter has filled the DataSet.

I think it should be absolutely possible that at runtime you pass a DataSet (with the exact structure of the one you used at design-time) to the report and the report would work without need for a data connection by its own.

Comment: thanks . i have over than 10 datatables with different fields,so i can't do this by wizard ! you mean is it possible with out wizard or not ?!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're describing, but there is an ADO.NET (XML) option which you can use to design and preview your report with sample data. It's replaced by the XML data passed in at runtime.